# Android Studio / Algunas imágenes con la librería Glide no cargan

Tags: android, glide

Hace muy poco tiempo me ayudaron a resolver un problema, aconsejandome que use la librería **Glide** para cargar **miniaturas** y **reducir** el lag de la aplicación. Esta efectivamente me funcionó y estoy cargando imágenes por medio de **URLs** en un RecyclerView las cuales algunas nunca cargan, o a veces cargan al interactuar con ellas por varias veces.

El problema es que al entrar al **fragment** que tiene el **recycler view con las image views**, estas muestran la **imágen de carga** (no la del **error** ni tampoco la que **debe** mostrar).

**Adjunto el código:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(adapter_recycler_chats.ViewHolderDatos holder, 
final int position) {

Glide.with(context).load(array_model_recycler_chat.get(position)
.getUrl_img_foto()).error(R.drawable.img_error).placeholder(
R.drawable.img_loading).into(holder.img_foto);
}

public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView img_foto;
    Context context;

    public ViewHolderDatos(View itemView, final Context context) {
        super(itemView);

        img_foto = 
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_foto_item_row_recycler_chat);
    }
}
```

**Adjunto el código que pone las vistas en el recycler:**

```
public void llenarRecycler(){
   array_model_chat.add(new model_recycler_chats("Jorge Hernandez","Hola 
   Tomas","Recibido a las 18:58","https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWWGZ.jpg"));
}
```

Agradecería que alguien pueda señalarme la causa de la **no carga** de las imágenes con la librería **Glide. Muchas gracias por leer!**

Comment: puede ser problema de memoria cache. Trata de agregarla primero al cache: .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) antes de .into

Comment: Gracias por comentar. Igualmente tu código no me sirvió :(

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía el mismo inconveniente con las versiones de Android <= 21, luego de varias pruebas y revisar la documentación, pude resolver el inconveniente implementando `SvgSoftwareLayerSetter` que esta en la documentación de [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/samples/svg/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/samples/svg/SvgSoftwareLayerSetter.java).

En mi caso, las imágenes descargadas son SVG, pero lo que hace esta clase no es específico para este formato de imagen, lo que hace es que asigna el valor `LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE` en la propiedad `layerType` de la vista donde se estaría mostrando la imagen, lo que permite que la imagen se muestre correctamente.

Puedes intentar usarlo para ver si soluciona tu inconveniente con imágenes JPG.

Un ejemplo de como usarlo:

`GlideApp.with(context).addListener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter()).error(errorDrawable).load(Uri.parse(url)).into(view);`